# Keycloak admin client

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I trying to use the keycloak client admin to create a user in my keycloak

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and with this code:

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder() //
                .serverUrl(serverUrl) //
                .realm(realm) //
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD) //
                .clientId(clientId) //
                .clientSecret(clientSecret) //
                .username("idm-admin") //
                .password("admin") //
                .build();

        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setUsername("tester1");
        user.setFirstName("First");
        user.setLastName("Last");
        user.setEmail("tom+tester1@tdlabs.local");
        user.setAttributes(Collections.singletonMap("origin", Arrays.asList("demo")));

        // Get realm
        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(realm);
        UsersResource userRessource = realmResource.users();

        // Create user (requires manage-users role)
        Response response = userRessource.create(user);
        System.out.println("Repsonse: " + response.getStatusInfo());
        System.out.println(response.getLocation());
        String userId = response.getLocation().getPath().replaceAll(".*/([^/]+)$", "$1");

        System.out.printf("User created with userId: %s%n", userId);

        // Get realm role "tester" (requires view-realm role)
        RoleRepresentation testerRealmRole = realmResource.roles()//
                .get("tester").toRepresentation();

        // Assign realm role tester to user
        userRessource.get(userId).roles().realmLevel() //
                .add(Arrays.asList(testerRealmRole));

        // Get client
        ClientRepresentation app1Client = realmResource.clients() //
                .findByClientId("app-javaee-petclinic").get(0);

        // Get client level role (requires view-clients role)
        RoleRepresentation userClientRole = realmResource.clients().get(app1Client.getId()) //
                .roles().get("user").toRepresentation();

        // Assign client level role to user
        userRessource.get(userId).roles() //
                .clientLevel(app1Client.getId()).add(Arrays.asList(userClientRole));

        // Define password credential
        CredentialRepresentation passwordCred = new CredentialRepresentation();
        passwordCred.setTemporary(false);
        passwordCred.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
        passwordCred.setValue("test");

        // Set password credential
        userRessource.get(userId).resetPassword(passwordCred);
```

But in my line  Response response = userRessource.create(user); the IDE show the error: Cannot access javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  I`m using spring-boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and java 1.8

Comment: did you get it to work? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: why do we need to pass both username password and client_id, client_secrets to work?

Answer (score 6):

If the problem is only related to

> Cannot access javax.ws.rs.core.Response

you have to add the following dependency in maven pom.xml if you are using Maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven, download the jar file and set in the classpath.

Answer (score 6):

Dependencies for `keycloak-admin-client` can be found at [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-admin-client/6.0.1)

Try these dependencies, it worked for me.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: u have some sample to send me please? tks

Comment: Do you mean creating User ?

Answer (score 0):

These libraries worked for me. Pay attention to the version though as my project was using an older version of spring. I used a few older libraries.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>15.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```